# Combining multiple tables using SQL Server Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, relational-database

As this goes without saying, I'm a severe novice when it comes to T-SQL and using SSMSE isn't my first option but I'm stuck with it and a poorly designed database. Essentially I'm trying to output the data from our current database so I can upload it to our new software and I need to get this data in manageable CSV files first.

I'm trying to move measurements associated with subjects in various studies but the data lies across several tables. The tables are as follows (primary keys listed first):

```
CREATE TABLE Study (StudyID int, StudyName nvarchar(50))

CREATE TABLE Subject (SubjectID int, SubjectName nvarchar(20), StudyID int)

CREATE TABLE Implant (ImplantID int, ImplantName nvarchar(255), StudyID int)

CREATE TABLE Measurement (MeasurementID int, SubjectID int, ImplantID int, 
                          Length float, Width float, Volume float, 
                          PerformDateTime datetime)
```

I know I'm new to databases but this topology really confused me. We have a lot of studies and I'd love to create an excel file for each study that organizes the data in the format for directly importing.  To do that I would need to generate a CSV file for each study that looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ImportStudy (SubjectName, PerformDateTime, Length, Width, Volume)
```

It's OK that the Subject Names would be repeated in the first column because that's how the new software inserts it. Any help would be great and save me about a month or two of my life even if I have to use a `WHERE StudyName LIKE N'ABC123'` and enter each one. If anyone can help me add the T-SQL equivalent of an Object Oriented "For Each" loop that would be amazing.  Thanks again for any help.

Best,
Jeff

Comment: Ok so now I get to take what was my simple question and make it slightly more challenging.  I forgot that there are a subset of subjects that have multiple implants.  This means two implants (of different implant IDs) have unique measurements (of different measurement IDs) for the same animal with the same PerformDateTime.  So my final table will have a Left-Length, Left-Width, Left-Volume and the same for Right.  Any suggestions.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want but getting a CSV file is pretty easy. If you'd like to extract the data you specified, run a query similar to this and have Management Studio output the results to a CSV file:

```
select Subject.SubjectName, 
       Measurement.PerformDateTime, 
       Measurement.Length, 
       Measurement.Width, 
       Measurement.Volume 
From Study 
inner join Subject on Study.StudyId = Subject.StudyId
inner join Implant on Study.StudyId = Implant.StudyId
inner join Measurement on Implant.ImplantId = Measurement.ImplantId
```

What's a bit strange with your schema is that you've linked Measurement to both Subjects and Implants. I've ignored the link from Subject to Measurement in the query above.

Comment: inner join is the default join type in T-SQL so just join is necessary

Comment: I always put inner / outer in as well. Terse is for people who get sleep on regular basis. :(

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was out of order with the joins so nothing was working for me.  I was hoping Management Studio could do a For-Each or something.  Either way I should be able to do it with windows commmand shell and running this as a batch process with sqlcmd.  I'm going to be winging that so any insights into sqlcmd & cmd would be welcomed.   Oh yeah I didn't design this schema. I just had the joy of dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly unsure of your question - are you asking how to export to CSV, or what the query should look like to generate your result set?

In any case, you can just build an ad-hoc SELECT statement in SSMS.  Once you've run it, you can select the results grid, right click, and select "Copy with Headers", and paste into Excel.

For building your query, without seeing the data, it appears as though the keys are named identically between the tables.  You can just join on those, and should be close to what you are looking for.

Basic idea:

```
SELECT
   S.SubjectName,
   M.PerformDateTime,
   M.Length,
   M.Width,
   M.Volume
FROM
   Subject Sub ON S.StudyID = Sub.StudyID
     INNER JOIN
   Measurements M ON Sub.SubjectID = M.SubjectID
```

If you need to filter by Study (your listed columns don't include the info), you can add this to the JOIN list as well, then filter in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Where would the Study filter go within the JOIN list @Dave? Sorry but again I've only been at this for a couple of months.  Make the mistake of telling your bosses that you took a java course in college and they assume you know everything about computers.